# Why is this generic Interface definition wrong?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, generic-programming

I am trying to write an interface that looks something like this

```
public interface IPropertyGroupCollection
{
    IEnumerable<IPropertyGroup> _Propertygroups { get;}
}

public interface IPropertyGroup
{
    IEnumerable<IProperty<T, U, V>> _conditions { get; }
}

public interface IProperty<T, U, V>
{
    T _p1 { get; }
    U _p2 { get; }
    V _p3 { get; }
}

public class Property<T, U, V> : IProperty<T, U, V>
{
    //Some Implementation
}
```

I keep on getting a compilation error for the ienumerable definition of _Conditions.

What am i doing wrong?
The Idea is the implementing classes will serve a generic property bag collection

Comment: Replace all generics with `object` and you are set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you haven't declared T, U and V:

```
public interface IPropertyGroup<T, U, V>
{
    IEnumerable<IProperty<T, U, V>> _conditions { get; }
}
```

You will have to add generic types to `IPropertyGroupCollection` as well.

Remember, `IProperty<bool,bool,bool>` is a different type to `IProperty<int,int,int>` despite the fact that they came from the same generic 'template'. You can't create a collection of `IProperty<T, U, V>`, you can only create a collection of `IProperty<bool, bool, bool>` or `IProperty<int int, int>`.

UPDATE:

```
public interface IPropertyGroupCollection
{
    IEnumerable<IPropertyGroup> _Propertygroups { get;}
}

public interface IPropertyGroup
{
    IEnumerable<IProperty> _conditions { get; }
}

public interface IProperty
{
}

public interface IProperty<T, U, V> : IProperty
{
    T _p1 { get; }
    U _p2 { get; }
    V _p3 { get; }
}

public class Property<T, U, V> : IProperty<T, U, V>
{
    //Some Implementation
}
```

Comment: Then how can i use the collection as a PropertyBag ? If I add the generic type to the collection interface?

Comment: Well, you can't use generics the way you want to use them.

Comment: So Is there a way in which I can define an interface that acts like a property bag?

Comment: Only if all property values derive from the same type.

Comment: I can restrict the property values to basic properties such as int/string/datetime/double .. frankly they are the only datatypes I care about as of now

Comment: Or loose generics. Create `public interface IProperty<T, U, V> : IProperty` ans have a collection of `IProperty`. But then you would need to cast down to concreate types.

Comment: @JakubKonecki can you elaborate that a  bit? I can try that

Comment: This is doable without downcasting to concrete types if you add properties to your classes one by one in the mixin-way. In such a case `PropertyGroup` ("property bag") is bad design.